# Opening a connection in SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce

I am trying to use SQLite in Windows ce 5.1.17.
I create a SQLite database using [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) in debug folder of my project.
Then I add System.Data.SQLite.dll and SQLite.Interop.065.dll to my project.
I am trying the following code to connect to database.

```
SQLiteConnection myConnection = null;
myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path. GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), Stock.s3db)+ "; Version=3; Cache Size =100");
                myConnection.Open();

                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from shops;";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                cmd.ExecuteReader();// I get exception no such table: shops
```

Also when I check myConnection database property it shows 'Database = "main"'. I do not know why database name is 'main', but in myConnection I set datasource to Stock.s3db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the connection string builder to ensure you get a correctly formatted string

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.FailIfMissing = true;
builder.DataSource = "Insert the fully qualified path to your sqlite db";
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside your Debug/Release folder, you'll probably find the empty database files created for you since the file you specify does not exist. 'main' is the standard db name with sqlite.

Copy your db in said folder for testing, or specifiy the full path in the connection string.

try this query to determine where the file you are using is located.

```
PRAGMA database_list
```

Comment: PRAGMA database_list query returns me 0.What does that mean?

Comment: Have you checked the state of your connection object? You need to determine if you are in 'Open' state.

Comment: I only got connection state open.Using Data Source=Stock.s3db in my connection string(But now database in main).if i give full path i get unable to open file. exception.(I copied Stock.s3db to output directory of my project.)

Comment: Do you still get an exception on ExecuteReader() though?

Comment: Maybe you should look into using SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder to ensure your connection string is properly formatted.

Comment: Yes SQLite error no such table: shops.
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from shops;";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Comment: Within your code, try creating a table, then put data in it, then do a select. This would ensure your sqlite stack is actually working.

Comment: When i create a table i could access it.Can you tell me at which location SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=STOCK.s3db; Version=3;"); creates database.

Comment: It probably depends on your dev settings. You can use ProcessExplorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine exactly what file a running process is using. Check you this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232830 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the database in the debug folder of the build output does *not* mean the file will end up on the target device.  You need to copy the database over to your target device (there are several mechanisms like a USB disk, Remote File Viewer, adding it as a Content item to your project, etc.).

I'd also be inclined to use a fully qualified path to the database, as CE doesn't have any concept of a working directory.

Comment: I use adding it as a Content item to my project,

Comment: Look in the device file system.  Is the file there?  Is it writable?  And again, use a fully-qualified path in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your database file is not in the correct folder. Try giving this line:

```
myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=Stock.s3db; Version=3;");
```

the full path to your database.

Comment: Now i got exception.
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: Unable to open the database file